# Field Calculator to generate a hyperlink

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, hyperlink

I am trying to create a hyperlink using the field calculator the problem is the field I am pulling from has numbers and letters and I only need to pull the numbers. I am currently using this field calculation
"http://imagedirector/documentsearch.aspx?Act=Display&&App=ENGDATA&&Qry=Valves,eq,"& [ValveNo]

because the field has the letters in there it pulls everything over... without creating another field is there anyway to tweak my existing code to get the ValveNo to return without the letter?

[image]

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to show?

Comment: What have you tried?  What research have you done?  Here is an explanation of how to use Python to extract all the digits from a text string by several different methods:  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-extract-numbers-from-string/ .  If you can't figure it out from there, then update your question to show more information about how you are using the Field Calculator.

Comment: This is what the hyperlink shows up as 

http://imagedirector/documentsearch.aspx?Act=Display&&App=ENGDATA&&Qry=Valves,eq,1001A

Its the hyperlink wording + the Valve number ... I need it to show up as the hyperlink text + Valve Number minus the letter